# Problemas conexión a base de datos MySQL desde C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Intento conectar MySQL y Visual C# de manera remota desde razyhosting para obtener datos, pero no funciona.

Éste es el error que me aparece:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Éste es  mi código de conexión:

```
public class Conexion
{
   public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
   {

      MySqlConnection conectar = new 
      MySqlConnection("server=xxxxxxxxx; database=xxxxxxxx; Uid=xxxxxxxx; pwd=xxxxxx;");

      conectar.Open();
      return conectar;  
   }
}
```

donde:

- server = host MySQL de mi servidor
- Uid = nombre de usuario MySQL

Con esos  datos  que  tengo  no logro  conectarme. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: de casualidad por algún lado en tu hosting te dice que puedes conectarte de manera remota? Algunos hosting gratuitos carecen de dicha feature. Saludos :D

Comment: Estas redirigiendo mal el host, es decir válida que el nombre del servidor este bien escrito, exista, que el servidor permita conexión remota o en su defecto este activo.

Comment: @EnriqueHurtado si está  activo, estoy trabajando con android y no he  tenido  ningún problema. Sólo que  quiero recuperar  algunos  registros de  mi base de  datos  con   c#  y no lo  consigo. De  hecho  estoy  tomando  los mismos  datos  con que  me conecto en  android

Comment: @fredyfx, estoy  trabajando  con android con  esta  misma base de datos . Eso indica que   puedo  conectarme  remotamente? estoy  tomando  los mismo datos de  conexión  que  tengo en  android  para  conectarme  con C#